# Choropleth map with proportional symbols in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geodataframe, imported with sf, which have information about 1874 districts of a Latinamerican country. It have this structure:

```
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  1874 obs. of  8 variables:
$ NOMBDIST: chr  "CODO DEL POZUZO" "TOURNAVISTA" "ALEXANDER VON HUMBOLDT" "IRAZOLA" ...
$ POBTOTAL: num  7768 6219 6085 10941 9003 ...
$ UBIGEO  : num  100902 100904 250305 250302 250304 ...
$ MC_PR   : num  41 41.4 46 43.8 35.3 ...
$ C_PR    : num  9.23 5.22 3.27 2.64 2.21 ...
$ TT      : num  1084 556 1530 2769 1535 ...
$ IDH     : num  0.324 0.409 0.423 0.378 0.437 ...
$ geom    :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 1874; first list element: List of 1
..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ : num [1:1294, 1:2] -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 -75.3 ...
..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
- attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geom"
- attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "NOMBDIST" "POBTOTAL" "UBIGEO" "MC_PR" ...
```

Where *NOMBIDST* is the name of the district; *POBTOTAL*, the total population of the district; *UBIGEO*, the unicode of the district; *MC_PR*, the percentage of women working in scientific positions; *C_PR*, the percentage of people working in scientific positions; *TT*, the total workers; and *IDH*, the Human Development Index.

I am trying to obtain a map where I have the districts as background (in gray color) and above them a point starting from the center of each one of them, whose size is a function of the *TT* column, and whose color is gradient according to the *MC_PR* column. Something like [this one](https://r-charts.com/es/espacial/mapa-simbolos-proporcionales-ggplot2/).

I had tried with this code:

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = gdf, fill = "grey95") +
geom_sf(data = centroides, pch = 21,
aes(size = TT, fill = MC_PR),
col = "grey20") +
xlim(c(2200000, 7150000)) +
ylim(c(1380000, 5500000)) +
scale_size(range = c(1, 9), guide = guide_legend(
direction = "horizontal",
nrow = 1,
label.position = "bottom")) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(5, "RdBu", rev = TRUE,alpha = 0.9)) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "")) +
theme_void() +
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

But I get this:

[image]

Is there a way to obtain it?

Comment: Can you share part of your data using `dput`?

Comment: *"I had tried with this code but unfortunately I don’t get what I want"* isn't that useful as a description of your issue. Could you please clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano the 'geometry' column makes it very difficult to share part of the file due to its length, so I uploaded it in GDrive, this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15qk3nuvt8M_eDUILndpyZP5oAJ7pnR0T/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @stefan I had edited the post to show the result.

Comment: Hm. Now I see what you mean. Have you already tried with removing `xlim()` and `ylim()`?

Answer (score 0):

As @stefan suggested in a comment, removing `xlim()` and `ylim()` works. This is the final code:

```
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = gdf, fill = "grey95") +
  geom_sf(
    data = centroides,
    pch = 21,
    aes(size = TT, fill = MC_PR),
    col = "grey20") +
  scale_size(
    range = c(1, 9),
    guide = guide_legend(
      direction = "horizontal",
      nrow = 1,
      label.position = "bottom")) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(5, "RdBu",
                                            rev = TRUE,
                                            alpha = 0.9)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```